# Do you know where to get the original iRobot Create?

Tags: irobot-create

Does anyone out there know where I can get the original iRobot Create?
The company no longer sells them. 
It was only 2 years ago that it was sold. It is white and its value is the physical design, that it has a large exposed deck for mounting armatures.
It is preprogrammed to operate in different configurations, eg. spinning, figure 8, following the outline of a wall, etc.
I have an ongoing art project using this model and as they are in operation everyday, I will eventually need to replace them with new ones.
To see a video of one of my projects you can go to https://vimeo.com/119486779
I currently have it working in a spinning motion.

Comment: Can you elaborate why a [Create 2](http://www.irobot.com/create) won't work for your project?

Comment: The physical design of the machine is not the same. I am using the flat bed tray to house an armature. Because of the design of the new one, I cannot adapt my existing armature to fit. I am also using the scripted spin program that exists in the Create 1 but not in the create 2.

Answer (score 1):

iRobot is no longer selling original Creates.  So your best bet is a secondary market like eBay.

However, the new Create 2 has the same API as the original.  (Using the Serial Command Interface, not the command module).  It did remove some of the lesser used functions like scripting, but added and improved many features.  Additionally, it is a more robust robot overall, and it even has a rechargeable battery.  I'd be surprised if the new Create 2 didn't work for your application.